# Updating Angular 5 variable value and binding in the view from jQuery function

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

I am facing a pretty awkward problem here...Angular 5 variable value from jQuery function is changing but not reflecting/binding the new value in the view:

**In the Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    declare var $: any;

    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    helloString: string = 'Hello World';

    ngOnInit() {
        $(() => {
          $(document).on('click', '#testButton', () => {
            this.helloString= "Not Hello World";
            console.log(this.helloString);
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

**In the HTML:**

```
    <div>{{helloString}}</div>

    //This button is in jQuery Datatable row..that's why I need the call function from jQuery

    <button type="button" id="testButton" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Test Button</button>
```

**The function is calling properly and *helloString* variable value is changing in the function and updated value is aslo showing in console but not reflecting in the view.Any help will be highly appreciated..**

Comment: it's probably not triggering angular's change detection cycle because it's external.  Try running it inside ngZone or just using the changedetector manually

Comment: Write the details code as answer please..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because your jquery method isn't triggering angular's change detection because it isn't registering as an asynchronous event in ngZone which is what angular uses to know when it should detect changes.

The best advice is to... not do this and remove jquery dependencies... but if you must, then you can run inside ngZone by using ngZone directly:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  helloString: string = 'Hello World';

  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    $(() => {
      $(document).on('click', '#testButton', () => {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
          this.helloString= "Not Hello World";
          console.log(this.helloString);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and now angular will know that something happened and it needs to change detect

Comment: sure, but just know that if you continue to try and mix angular and jquery you'll be fighting the framework the whole way rather than letting it make your life easier.  Angular is super opinionated in how it wants you to do things, it's only fun to use when if you commit

Comment: Yes! it works..I know the fact but I have no alternative to jQuery Datatale in Angular..There is Angular Datatable but this is not matured yet as Jquery Datatable..That's why I am obliged to top jquery Datatable in Angular..

Comment: There are a lot of data table plugins properly integrated with angular, ngPrime, angular material are two that are much better options

Comment: Tried..But these don't fulfill my requirements like Jquery DataTable :P

Answer (score 4):

This is totally wrong approach bringing jquery in side your code.Learn the basics from [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onClickMe()">Click</button>
    Your message : {{clickMessage}}`
})
export class ClickMeComponent {
  clickMessage = '';

  onClickMe() {
    this.clickMessage = 'New Message!';
  }
}
```

If you still stick to your current approach then you have to manually trigger change detection.One of the way I know is to use NgZone.

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';
```

Execute the run method with a callback

```
NgZone.run()
```

Another option is to use `ChangeDetectorRef`.

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class Component {
  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  yourMethod() {
    //do some work
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Man I know this...My button is in jQuery Datatable...I must have to call it from jQuery function..

Comment: just an fyi, ngzone needs to be injected just lke the change detector

Comment: @TanvirArjel It's understandable that jQuery should be used for its plugins sometimes. This doesn't mean that you should keep using jQuery for everything, including things that are supposed to be done with Angular, such as event management. There are some cases where ngZone.run is inevitable but here it is used as a hack and indicates that something went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..Its up-voted..I know the fact but I have no alternative to jQuery Datatale in Angular..There is Angular Datatable but this is not matured yet as Jquery Datatable..That's why I am obliged to top jquery Datatable in Angular..

Answer (score 2):

The problem results from the fact that events that aren't handled by Angular  (jQuery `click`) run out of current zone, this makes impossible to detect changes that were made in event handler.

A quick fix is to run the code in zone with [`NgZone` `run`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) (as another answer already explained):

```
  $(document).on('click', '#testButton', () => {
    ngZone.run(() => {
      this.helloString= "Not Hello World";
    });
  });
```

Considering that jQuery is necessary for its plugins and cannot be eliminated from the component, the remaining problem is that event isn't set up by Angular.

This is done with `Renderer2` provider. It is a good practice to execute relative queries, considering that `#testButton` resides in current component and can be queried from `ElementRef` (and it should, for encapsulation reasons):

```
  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    const buttonElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementById('testButton');

    this.unlistenButton = this.renderer2.listen(buttonElement, 'click', () => {
      this.helloString= "Not Hello World";
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unlistenButton();
  }
```